# How to use SDL2 as 3d-party dependencie on my static ( CMake ) library?

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I am on Linux and I am having trouble using SDL2 with my CMake projects that using my static library. When I am Linking my_static_library with my_custom_project, I get *undefined reference* from SDL2 calls, although I have linked SDL2 with my static library.

For example:
***my_static_library CMakeLists.txt***

```
[...]

# SDL2 package
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
if (SDL2_FOUND)
  message(STATUS ${SDL2_LIBRARY} " SDL2 Library has been found!")
  include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find SDL2 Library!")
endif()

[...]

add_library(my_static_library STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(nile_static PUBLIC ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

***my_custom_project CMakeLists.txt***

```
[...]

target_include_directories(${PRODUCT_NAME} PRIVATE
  ${MY_STATIC_LIB_DIR}/include)

[...]

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} my_static_lib})
```

Any other dependencie linkes as expected ( OpenGL, glew, stb, freetype, etc.) except for SDL2.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Are **both** `CMakeLists.txt` compiled as a part of the **single** CMake **project**, or they are different CMake projects?

Comment: They are compiled as different CMake projects.

Answer (score 0):

If your static library dynamically links to SDL2, you should add a search for SDL2 to your project depending on your project.